# Does the Schwinger effect prove matter and antimatter can be created from a vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, antimatter, matter, pair-production

Virtual particles or vacuum fluctuations are the pair annihilation/creation of matter and antimatter particles in and out of the vacuum. Theses particles are virtual, but we know they exist because of their effects.

However, the Schwinger effect is when a strong electric field creates real matter and antimatter particles out of a vacuum.

Does this prove matter and antimatter can be created from a vacuum?

There are multiples articles that prove they come from the vacuum.

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/10/111028142508.htm

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/endless-creation-out-of-nothing/

http://naturalunits.blogspot.com/2015/04/the-super-critical-charge.html

Comment: Please do not delete the content of a question by editing it. What did you intend to do with that edit?

Comment: I wanted to delete it because of all the dislikes

Comment: The people here are demotivating and harsh.

Comment: Stop changing this question. You have already received several answers here and you should not edit the question in a way that makes the answers seem nonsensical because you removed the question they replied to.

Comment: What does it mean for matter and antimatter to “equal nothing?” Both matter and antimatter clearly *exist*, so without further elaboration I don’t know what that sentence means.

Answer (score 5):

Energy is not considered "nothing" anywhere in physics.

You need energy in order to create your strong field. It even has its own mass.

In fact, there are quite a few ways to create particle-antiparticle pairs.

They all boil down to "give the virtual pair enough energy to make them real".

---

edit:

The real and the virtual particles differ by their energy. Real particles have energy, virtual particles have not.

When you use electromagnetic field to kick the virtual particles into "reality", your field loses energy corresponding to the rest mass of the particles (and some more because they don't emerge at rest).

Both "real" and "virtual" particles are models of what happens in the universe.

Depending on the theoretical framework you are using in a particular case, you may or may not need the virtual ones (the real ones are more or less always used).

In particular, the Casimir effect can be modelled pretty much without the virtual ones, it is just easier and more consistent with other models when you use them.

Comment: What about vacuum fluctuations or virtual particles that are popping in and out of existence everywhere?

Comment: Virtual particles also occur everywhere in space time and don’t always require energy.

Comment: @lego snow: The point is that in the presence of an electric field, these virtual particles can actually become real with a corresponding drop in the energy of the electric field. Without the electric field, these virtual particles remain virtual and disappear back into the vacuum.

Comment: But, we know they exist because of their effects, such as the casimir effect.

Comment: Both "real" and "virtual" particles are models of what happens in the universe. Depending on the theoretical framework you are using in a particular case, you may or may not need the virtual ones (the real ones are more or less always used). In particular, the Casimir effect can be modelled pretty much without the virtual ones, it is just easier and more consistent with other models when you use them. The real and the virtual particles differ by their energy. Real particles have energy, virtual particles have not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the physicists nothing is, philosophically speaking, is not nothing at all. Nothing, being no thing, is not even equal to anything including itself as there is no thing to compare against.

More correctly put, as you have noted, is that virtual particles are quantum fluctuations of the vacuum. The Schwinger effect is when in the presence of an electric field these virtual particles become actual with a corresponding drop of the electric field energy equal to the rest mass of the particles.

Now, an electric field is not nothing. Hence the particles have not come from nothing.

It's worth noting that a prediction of QFT, is that is relativistic  QM that particle number is not conserved - and this is what we see here. It's also worth noting that it was Fritz Sauter who first predicted the effect in 1931, twenty years before Schwinger gave a full theoretical justification.

Answer (score 0):

Matter and antimatter are produced with the electric field **sources**.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not prove they come from the vacuum. You need energy in the electric field to create a matter antimatter pair. The amount of power required is not zero and is given by the following formula:

$$ e = \sqrt{\vec{e}} \left( \sqrt{ \vec{e}} \right) \tag{1} \label{1} $$

$$ b = \sqrt{\vec{b}} \left( \sqrt{ \vec{b}} \right) \tag{2} \label{2} $$

Virtual particles are off the mass shell. They do not satisfy the equations of motions and we have no good reason to believe they exist outside the math. They are the a merely a mathematical symbol of  quantum fields.

You need the ***strong electric field*** to create actual matter antimatter particles.

*Electric field → Matter & Antimatter*

$$ E = m c^{2} \tag{3} \label{3} $$

[image]